# Registration Facebook user with Django Allauth

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I tried to use Django AllAuth to make a registration user by Facebook.

I have to make a REST API so I would to use Django REST Framework.

I found this simple [tutorial](http://bytefilia.com/titanium-mobile-facebook-application-django-allauth-sign-sign/) to make the first user registration but probably there are some difference from current implementation:

I tried this code:

```
def post(self, request):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        access_token = data.get('access_token', '')

        try:
            app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
            token = SocialToken(app=app, token=access_token)

            # check token against facebook
            login = fb_complete_login(app, token)
            login.token = token
            login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)

            # add or update the user into users table
            ret = complete_social_login(request, login)

            # if we get here we've succeeded
            return Response(status=200, data={
                'success': True,
                'username': request.user.username,
                'user_id': request.user.pk,
            })

        except:

            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response(status=401, data={
                'success': False,
                'reason': "Bad Access Token",
            })
```

but now I see that `fb_complete_login` take 3 parameters: `request`, `app` and `token`.

So, I tried  to put also the request like this function parameter but some lines later I have an error on l`ogin = fb_complete_login(app, token)`.

> TypeError: add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not
>   'Request'.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: It's trying to use Django's messaging system with a Django Rest Framework request object (the 'Request') rather than a HttpRequest object which it expects.  I have a similar issue and not sure if this is the configuration or if this is a bug. As a quick fix, you can disable 'django.contrib.messages' in your settings.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution given here: http://tech.agilitynerd.com/django-rest-registration-with-django-rest-auth.html

To disable messaging just for allauth, override the adapter (for instance in main.adapters):

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MessageFreeAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def add_message(self, request, level, message_template,
                        message_context=None, extra_tags=''):
        pass
```

then add this in settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main.adapters.MessageFreeAdapter'
```

Comment: I am using the same tutorial and tried the specified fix but I still get the error --  fb_complete_login take 3 parameters: request, app and token.